# Visual Studio Solution Explorer, Highlight Active Item color

Tags: visual-studio-2008, solution-explorer

In Visual Studio 2008, is there any way to change the background color of the highlighted item in the Solution Explorer? The current setting makes the item quite visible when the Solution Explorer has focus (blue), but when the editor has focus, the background color is a very light gray, which makes it near impossible to see. I hate having to navigate to a type's definition, and then have to give the Solution Explorer focus to see where in the solution the current file lies.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is related to a system color named "3D Objects" in the advanded color selector dialog box of Windows.
If you change this color, using aero themes, it affects MDI windows and it also changes the color of the selected item in an inactive window.
Logic, isn'it ???
Hope this will be helpfull.

Pierre.

Comment: Crisis Pierre, you're my hero... I dunno how this will affect other systems, but on my machine (Windows 7 with Aero enabled), changing this setting does change the selected item color in VS, with minimal impact on other settings (a few control panel windows inherit this color, as well as the active tab in Firefox).

Comment: (Amongst other things, worth it IMO)

Comment: To be exact, on Win7 it's in Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Personalization\Window Color and Appearance\Advanced....

Comment: thank you that clarification Marcel. It was driving me nuts to find that setting.

Comment: Windows 7: Search for "Windows colors and metrics" > change Item to "3D Objects" > change color ... alternate solution: right click file in Visual Studio 2008 > select "Locate in Solution Explorer" or create a macro that does the same thing

Answer (score 3):

Turns out this is a Windows setting, and VS has no control over it. If you want to delve into the dark art of custom windows skinning with a Hex editor (as is needed for Vista), then there is a tutorial [here](http://ukintel.deviantart.com/art/Vista-Hex-Editing-Tutorial-0-7-60297439) on how this can be done. Unsure which property of a Windows Theme affects this behavior though, as all that is mentioned in that tutorial is the Selected Item Highlighting when a window has focus.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors > Display Items > Selected Text.
Set the Item Background colour (eg, I set mine to Magenta so it really stands out).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to windows because all the treeviews in windows behave like this. you can make sure by checking the "Explorer" folder Tree.
I tried to find how we can change the highlight color for Selected Items after it loses focus I couldn't find anything helpful.

related topics:

[Change background color of Solution Explorer in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189043/change-background-color-of-solution-explorer-in-visual-studio)

[2008 Solution Explorer Focus colors](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbide/thread/5c714596-b81b-44c4-bb83-0363989af3f1)