# How do I apply themes to Solution Explorer in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, themes

I've applied the [Zenburn 2010](http://studiostyles.info/schemes/zenburn-2010) theme to VS2010 without too much trouble. The next problem I have is that the Solution Explorer (and every other pane) is still coming up in the default white colour scheme. How do I go about applying the theme (or suitable alternative) to these panes?

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change background color of Solution Explorer in Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189043/change-background-color-of-solution-explorer-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to a [response](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/20cd93a2-c435-4d00-a797-499f16402378) from Matthew Johnson from Microsoft on a Q&A page about theming VS2010 (click on Q&A tab, his response is most of the way down the page):

> The Solution Explorer is not WPF-based
>   in VS 2010, and is still a Win32
>   common tree view control. As such, the
>   tree view is rendered using the
>   current Windows theme.

So it looks like it will only change if you change your Windows theme colors/fonts.

Comment: I agree.  Kind of defeats the purpose of an overall theme.

Answer (score 1):

actually its possible now. just download and install the add on

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/76b86cc7-7838-4b12-bbb9-a69985b663ed