# Is there a way to change the background color of the Solution Explorer in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-sdk

In Visual Studio 2010 I can use `SendMessage` to change the background color of the Solution Explorer just like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189043/change-background-color-of-solution-explorer-in-visual-studio). Since Visual Studio 2012 uses WPF this method is no longer working for me. I can do this with other windows such as Class View, Data Sources, and Server Explorer but the Solution Explorer doesn't show up in Spy++.

I've looked through the SDK but haven't found anything that will allow me to change the style of this window. Using `DTE2` I'm able to get a reference to the Solution Explorer but this looks to be for the hierarchy items only and not the actual tree view control or window pane.

I came across an [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee818135.aspx) showing how to change the text editor colors using the `IWpfTextViewCreationListener` interface but as the name suggests it only works with the text editor. Is there a way to do the same thing but for other windows such as the Solution Explorer?

Answer (score 2):

Check out this question: [How do you change the background colour for Solution Explorer in Visual Studio 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096368/how-do-you-change-the-background-colour-for-solution-explorer-in-visual-studio-2)

> Use this Utility
>
> http://bchavez.bitarmory.com/archive/2012/08/27/modify-visual-studio-2012-dark-and-light-themes.aspx
>
> Use Category TreeView

Answer (score 0):

Color theme editor came out
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/366ad100-0003-4c9a-81a8-337d4e7ace05